# how can get value form Radio button from first click an selection android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I choose the first choice (correct answer), click Submit to take the value and update the variable does not happen, but when  click on the second option without clicking on submit button and back and click on the first option and press submit, it takes the value and the variable updated.
how can take the value from the first selection.
xml

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton0"
                style="@style/MyRadio"
                android:text="True"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                style="@style/MyRadio"
                android:text="False"  />
        </RadioGroup>
```

java

```
 RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            score2=0;
            switch(checkedId){

                case R.id.radioButton0:
                    score2+=0;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    score2+=10;
                    break;


            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When `radioButton0` is clicked, you aren't doing anything. You are adding 0 to 0.

Additionally, each time you click a radio button the value is reset, since `score2=0` is inside `onCheckedChanged`.